# Azure Boards Approval on Work Item/ Tasks

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-boards

Hi Azure DevOps Community and Stackoverflow community,

We are currently implementing Azure Boards as our project management tool, but one major requirement in our project is to integrate task approval in the work item by management / team leads.
Our current process is to seek manual email approval and attach it to the work item which lengthens turnaround time.

Is there any way to implement this feature in Azure Boards?

Here is our expected flow:
App team creates work item -> Management leads will approve -> DevOps will do the task

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want is not possible with DevOps.

Can the approval process built into the pipeline be inadequate for this purpose?

So you start the release - the appropriate approvers are set up here - and only when the "pre-deployment condition" is accepted by the approver, does the actual release start? They will be notified by e-mail.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass

Or you can use something like this with the classic pipeline: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-webhooks-webhook?view=azure-pipelines

Listening on a webhook and checking conditions.

Comment: Hi @KKI Thank you for your inputs. For the approach 1, it seems good but I see that every time they commit changes to the repo and trigger the pipeline, it has to go through the conditions such as approval and window hours? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: The approach 1 would be good if it is only applicable in Release/ Deployment Pipelines only.

Answer (score 0):

There are not built-in features to meet your full requirement. Also do not find any workaround to do this.

If your projects really need this feature, I recommend you try to report a feature request on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest). This will make it more convenient for the product teams to receive and understand your ideas. And your feedback also could be helpful for improving the Azure DevOps products.